# JW Player and Amazon S3: Private videos, how to manage public and private key? Where should I put those keys to play the video inside my site?

Tags: video, amazon-s3, jwplayer

I´ve got JWPlayer installed and I´ve got an Amazon S3 bucket with some videos.
Those videos are meant to be private, allowing only my site´s visitors to watch them.

Now, I´ve got this code, that´s working:

```
<div id='container'>Loading the player ...</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
 jwplayer('container').setup({
  flashplayer: '/jwplayer/player.swf',
  file: 'http://content.longtailvideo.com/videos/flvplayer.flv',
  height: 270,
  width: 480
 });
</script>
```

What I don´t know how to manage is the Amazon´s video itself. I mean, I have a public and a private key, where should I put them? Because if I just post the video´s links (https://...) it won´t play, because it salys "forbidden" (naturally).

Any ideas on what should I do? I´ve look into jwplayer´s API and didn´t found anything, not at the [setup wizard](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard)...

Any help will be very much appreciated!
Rosamunda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should provide a proxy for auth, setting a server side cookie for user's session in order to let him watch your video but avoid embedding it or linking it on different domains.

There's no other way to do it without letting videos to be public.

Sorry if this comes a little late (I just saw your question).